# I want to write to a Vlookup statement

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I want to write to a Vlookup statement. I'm populating text boxes in a VBA form with a series of:

With frmDragonInfo

```
.txtInfo6 = Application.Text(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DrLevel + 1, Range(DrCode), 2), "[hh]:mm")
```

Then, having updated the text boxes, I want to click a cmd button on the form write it back again with:

With Sheets("DataList")

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DrLevel, Range(DrCode), 2) = txtInfo1.Text
```

DrLevel is a number from 1 to 100 & DrCode is a named range on the 'DataList' sheet.
That doesn't work. Can I write to a Vlookup? if so, How? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim f As Range

Set f = Sheets("DataList").Range(DrCode).find(DrLevel, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not f Is Nothing Then
    f.Offset(0,1).Value = txtInfo1.Text
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Both .find and 'If Not f Is Nothing Then' are new to me but the answer works perfectly. Learning all the time :)

Comment: I suspect that the OP was looking for an exact match in the first column of `Range(DrCode)` though his sample did not express that. Using `.Find` as you have done looks at the entire range and may be problematic depending on the nature of the data matrix. Incorporating `SearchOrder:=xlByColumns` would at least give the first column priority in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to rely on the worksheet functions for everything. VBA has is own version of `Application.Text`.

```
.txtInfo6 = Format(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DrLevel + 1, Range(DrCode), 2), "[hh]:mm")
```

Should that have the (optional) *range_lookup* parameter set to *False* for an exact match? ([VLOOKUP function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx))

Use `.Columns(1)` to slice off the first column of `Range(DrCode)` and look backwards.

```
dim rw as long
rw = application.match(DrLevel + 1, Range(DrCode).Columns(1), 0)
Range(DrCode).cells(rw, 2) = txtInfo1.Text
```

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. This answer works fine too. I'd vote both answers UP if I was allowed to!! Cheers.

Comment: @WireTalents - I've upvoted Tim's response for you. You *should* click the checkmark to acknowledge it as the accepted answer.